# How to re-write this double variables url in htaccess in to pretty url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf, friendly-url

I just want this URL

```
example.com/?cat_page_10=2
```

into this URL

```
example.com/cat-page/10/2.html
```

the above URL has two (double) vairables 10 and 2 are both are flexable/dynamic variables they will change according to requested page.

i tried this

```
RewriteRule ^cat-page/([^/]*)\.html$ /?cat_page_10=$1 [L]
```

But result is this

```
http://example.com/cat-page/2.html
```

and i want this

```
example.com/cat-page/10/2.html
```

Because 10 is also dynamic variable in url so iw ant both will change according to requested url
Anyone help me out where i mistake?

Comment: _"i tried this [...] But result is this [...]"_ - that makes no sense. You are rewriting _from_ `cat-page/xyz.html` _to_ `/?cat_page_10=xyz` here. This is not an external redirect, so there is no external URL "resulting from" this. That your links correctly point to `/cat-page/10/2.html` in the first place, is something you need to handle when you create your HTML output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing `RewriteRule` pattern is not correct as it allows only one `/` after `/cat_page`.

You may use this rule:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?cat_page_([\w-]+)=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cat-page/%1/%2.html? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal rewrite from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^cat-page/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ ?cat_page_$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: RewriteRule will never match a query string, this answer is not valid

Comment: This is not for matching query string, this is for rewriting `example.com/cat-page/10/2.html` to `example.com/?cat_page_10=2`.

Comment: well his post says he wants the query string one into the non query string one , not the opposite.

Comment: Hope you noted OP's rule also

Answer (score 0):

**Query Strings** (everything after the ? character) **are never matched by a RewriteRule**, you need a RewriteCond to check the query string

I think you could go with something simple like this, it depends if those variables are always numbers or something else.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_page_(\d+)=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^ /cat-page/%1/%2.html [R,L]
```

PS: sorry I didn't get in time at #httpd to help.